# Detect string repetition in python without regular expression

Tags: python, recursion

I would like a function to detect string reputation, specifically

> repetition("abcabcabc")
>   abc
>
> repetition("aaaaaaa")
>   a
>
> repetition("ababab")
>   ab
>
> repetition("abcd")
>   abcd

I am thinking of doing it in a recursive way but I am confused

Thanks for any help in advance!

I am trying something like

```
def repetition(r):
    if len(r) == 2:
       if r[0] == r[1]:
          return r[0]
    half = len(r) / 2
    repetition(r[:half])
    if r[:half] == r[half:]:
       return r[:half]
```

Comment: And what would ababa be?

Comment: I assume ababa would be ababa, what I want is bascially detect the sub string of a repetitive string, like "abababab" will give me ab

Comment: I am solving the regular expression case \*, like (ab)\* matches ababab, I need to detect the substring first

Comment: What is your question? "Please write this function for me from scratch"?

Comment: The algorithm you're probably looking for: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#Python

Comment: it's like a I was given a regex tree, consider regular expression with just 0, 1 and operator '|' and '*', write a function regular(rx, s) where rx is the regular expression and s is the string, return True if rx matches s

Comment: Two thoughts on the code you posted: 1. I do not understand the first `if` block. What do you want to do here? 2. This approach will not work for all cases as you are assuming the string to be symmetrical. But what about `abcabcabc`?

Comment: That's like the base case, but I forgot the case "aaaaaaa"

Answer (score 1):

There probably is a better way to do this, but my first thought would be this:

```
def repetition(string):
    substring = ''
    for character in string:
        substring += character
        if len(string) % len(substring) == 0:
            if (len(string) / len(substring)) * substring == string:
                return substring
```

Comment: what do u mean by * substring? since substring is a string, how can you multiply it?

Comment: This is a great Python feature: `2 * "test" == "testtest"`.

Comment: Wow cool solution, my bad, I can multiply string

Comment: In the second last line I assume you need to convert (len(string) / len(substring)) to int

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re
def repetitions(s):
    r = re.compile(r"(.+?)\1+")
    for match in r.finditer(s):
        if len(match.group()) != len(s): 
            return s

    return match.group(1)
```

Test:

```
repetitions("oblabla")
#output: "oblabla"

repetitions("blabla")
#output: "bla"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am prohibited from use regex pattern